# Do we need local server to clone a repo from cloud in plasticscm

Tags: plasticscm

Do we need local server to clone repo from cloud. I tried to clone using `cm clone repo1@<organame>@cloud` It gives me error

> Source and destination repositories are the same
> ('repo1@@cloud')

. Can't we just clone a repo like we do in git using "git clone" and it just copy the floder to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The "**cm clone**" command requires a **src_rep_spec** and **dst_rep_spec** parameters as it clones from a source to a destination repository.

More info on **cm clone --help**.

if you just want to download a copy of a repository in certain changeset you should use  you should use **"cm wk create"** (Create a workspace).

More info on **cm wk create --help**.